# showing only country code in material-select angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use this in HTML

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 70px;margin-left: 50px;">
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select (openedChange)="toogleCountry()" [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option value="+91">
      <span>{{"+91"}}</span>
      <span *ngIf="showCountry">{{"india"}}</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

and this in component.ts by using (openChange) event of mat-select

```
showCountry = false;
toogleCountry() {
      this.showCountry = !this.showCountry;
  }
```

but I am getting the desired result after I remove focus from mat select

Comment: What do you expect to show in this?

Comment: only the country code after selection...but if user clicks again on dropdown, it should display both country code and country name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mat-select-trigger` to achieve what you want. You just have to define what should be visible after the user selected an option, e.g. `<mat-select-trigger> {{ selected?.code }} </mat-select-trigger>`.

```html
<mat-form-field style="width: 70px;margin-left: 50px;">
    <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
        <mat-select-trigger>
            {{ selected?.code }}
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let opt of countries" [value]="opt">{{opt.code}} - {{opt.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Have a look at this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-custom-trigger) for a working example.